# Parsing object when array field sometime can be null

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have json like

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "reference": null
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "reference": [
        {
          "name": name,
          "data": "data"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have create classes

```
class MyList
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "list")]
    public IList<MyObject> list;
}
class MyObject
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int id;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "reference")]
    public IList<Reference> reference = null;
}

class Reference
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public string data;
}
```

and by using

```
MyList mylist = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyList>(response,
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,
                    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
                });
```

I got exception

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[SBM.Actions.WebServices.WorkCenter.API.ResManJsonClient+MenuItem]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'list[0].myobject[0].reference.name', line 1, position *.

How to handle such jsons?

Attached test project https://github.com/oleksiizozulenko/for-defects

Comment: With the exception of the unquoted value `name` in your JSON, what you posted works fine for me.

Comment: I've tested again. It doesn't work With the same error:   Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: n. Path 'list[1].reference[0].name', line 11, position 19.

Comment: Then there's something wrong somewhere else in the code you're using, besides what you've posted. Your code sample is not sufficient to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @Andrew Whitaker indicated in the comments, your JSON is invalid.  The value of the `name` property needs to be quoted.

In your test.json file you have:

```
      "name": MyName,
```

It should be:

```
      "name": "MyName",
```

Once you fix that problem, your test project runs fine (no errors).